# Returning corresponding row based on fuzzywuzzy ratio

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy, fuzzywuzzy

I'm using fuzzy wuzzy to compare two columns in two different dataframes. I'd like to retrieve a corresponding value in the same row but different column within df2. For example:

If i in df1 column A has a match ratio of more than 50 with df2 column A, I'd like to retrieve the corresponding value in df2 column B.

my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
df1=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\nkurdob\\Desktop\\Sheet1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\nkurdob\\Desktop\\Sheet2.csv')


for i in range(len(df1)):
    em = df1['A'][i]
    test = fuzz.partial_ratio(em, df2['A']) 
    while test > 50:
        print df1['Fund Name'][i]==df2['B']
```

This goes into a never ending output - I have to stop it every time. Does anyone know how to retrieve the corresponding row in df2 based on a certain match ratio?

Thanks
Nazar

Answer (score 1):

Replace `while` with `if`

You have already run the partial_ratio function and obtained your static result named `test`. if it is > 50 it will forever be > 50 in that part of your code causing infinite looping.

Comment: Do you know how I can bring back a corresponding row based on a specific ratio result?